# Linq repeat creation of empty object?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to do the following:

```
var newObjects = Enumerable.Repeat(new MyClass(), 10);
myList.AddRange(newObjects);
```

The above obviously doesn't work because the same instance is added 10 times. However, is there something similar that can be used or do I need to use a `for` loop?

Comment: ``Enumerable.Range``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to put a placeholder in `Enumerable.Repeat`, and then use a projection to construct your instances:

```
var newObjects = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).Select(x => new MyClass());
```

NOTE: In the example you provided, you are consuming `newObjects` immediately, so it should be ok for this to be an `IEnumerable`. In general, be careful not to enumerate `newObjects` more than once, or you may have the side effect of creating additional unexpected instances of `MyClass`.  Since this expression has the side effect of constructing instances, it would probably be better to immediately materialize it with `ToList` or `ToArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899(v=vs.100).aspx

You get always the same instance and not 10 different objects.

Take this example:

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  list.Add(new MyClass());